# How to align positions to 3 sections, up - middle and bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling to put 3 sections in the positions I want in a full-screen page, the 1st on the upper part of the page below the links in the container, the 2nd section in the middle of the page and the 2rd on the bottom.

I use bootstrap for this and a jQuery resize function. How can I achieve this and keep the positions on responsive too?

Here is the jsfiddle I constructed for this http://jsfiddle.net/froszacn/2/

and here is the code

Thank you

```
<section class="full-screen-mobile">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                <ul class="list-inline text-right inner-nav">
                    <li><a href="https://www.domain.com/">LINK</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.domain.com/">LINK</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="var-screen">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="margin-left:-15px;margin-top:50px">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-10 col-lg-12 text-left" style="visibility: visible;">
                    <div class="logo-container">
                        <img id="index-logo" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3667382710/d2d5d04262024df77b1769a3d2c13c00_normal.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                     <h2 style="letter-spacing:-1px;">upper section</h2>

                    <div class="divide-xs"></div>
                    <p class="lead" style="font-size:17px;">upper section<br>------</p>
                    <div class="buttons" id="download-button">
<a class="koumpi windows" href="https://www.domain.com/download">middle section<p class="sub-text">middle section</p>
</a> 
                        <p style="font-size:13px;margin-top:3px;">middle section<br>----</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="download-apps">
                        <p>bottom section</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Expected result

[image]

Comment: what is the problem now?? Your fiddle, though does not load css properly, has been set whatever you need!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I want these 3 sections to be in the top of the page, in the middle of the page and in the bottom of the page. For now, they are not.

Comment: can you post screenshots of how you want and how it is now since it's not clear in the fiddle for me!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I have updated my question with the screenshot, thank you!

Comment: so you are telling it's not covering the whole page??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I am telling that I want to put the "upper part" below the links container, the "middle" in the middle of the page, and the bottom in the bottom of the page

Comment: Ok.. For bottom I can say that you have to add two style properties as below: `position:fixed; bottom:0px`. and still am confused with the upper and middle part.!! Upper part is right below links container but UI wise its to the left side and Links are to the right side!! you want upperpart right under links container??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao No, i want the upper part as shown in the screenshot. I want the links to stay on the right side. Bottom 0px is not responsive

Answer (score -1):

```
<!--use the code for top fixed header-->
<div class="navbar-fixed-top">header area <div>


<!--use the code for align the area in the middle-->
<div class="vertical-center-row">middel area</div>


<!--use the code for sticky footer-->
<div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">footer area</div>


[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/froszacn/8/
```

Comment: What is the vertical-center-row?

Comment: I need the sections to be in the container, not in the entire page